# How to insert date into MySQL DATETIME column from Angular using Node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular

I have date picker in my application. I want to insert the selected date into a MySQL database column with `DATETIME` data type.

This is the value of the date picker in Angular using `console.log(date.value)` :

```
Tue Nov 12 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Israel Standard Time)
```

Which format does the date need to be converted to for MySQL database insertion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To ensure consistency, it is helpful to store all dates in the UTC timezone.

### Step 1: Convert JavaScript Date to ISO (UTC timezone)

```
const isoDateString: string = datePickerDate.toISOString();
```

This also enables sending the date via JSON to the server.

### Step 2: Ensure that MySQL timezone is UTC

```
cursor.execute("SET time_zone = '+00:00'")
```

### Step 3: Format date for MySQL insertion

On the Node.js server, parse the ISO date string (from step 1) and format as:
**'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'**

```
const isoDate = new Date(isoDateString);
const mySQLDateString = isoDate.toJSON().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
```

### [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html)

> MySQL recognizes DATETIME and TIMESTAMP values in these formats:
>
> As a string in either **'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'** or **'YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'**
>   format. A “relaxed” syntax is permitted here, too: Any punctuation
>   character may be used as the delimiter between date parts or time
>   parts. For example, '2012-12-31 11:30:45', '2012^12^31 11+30+45',
>   '2012/12/31 11*30*45', and '2012@12@31 11^30^45' are equivalent.
>
> The only delimiter recognized between a date and time part and a
>   fractional seconds part is the decimal point.
>
> The date and time parts can be separated by T rather than a space. For
>   example, '2012-12-31 11:30:45' '2012-12-31T11:30:45' are equivalent.
>
> As a string with no delimiters in either 'YYYYMMDDHHMMSS' or
>   'YYMMDDHHMMSS' format, provided that the string makes sense as a date.
>   For example, '20070523091528' and '070523091528' are interpreted as
>   '2007-05-23 09:15:28', but '071122129015' is illegal (it has a
>   nonsensical minute part) and becomes '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.
>
> As a number in either YYYYMMDDHHMMSS or YYMMDDHHMMSS format, provided
>   that the number makes sense as a date. For example, 19830905132800 and
>   830905132800 are interpreted as '1983-09-05 13:28:00'.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:{{yourDate | date: 'yyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS'}} then send it to controller and then save into db